# Passing Object Reference to JS Interop in Blazor WASM

Tags: event-handling, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-jsinterop, calendly

I have been working on group Blazor WASM project with a server side API. As per requirement I have integrated Calendly API for event scheduling.
Inside a card component I have embedded the following code provided from their website:

```
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/my-app/my-event" style="min-width:320px;height:630px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" async></script>
```

[Calendly uses window.postMessage()](https://calendly.stoplight.io/docs/embed-api-docs/ZG9jOjI2NzAyMzk-notifying-the-parent-window) to post events to the parent window so I invoke the following code on component initialization to 'intercept' the events and make some calls to Calendly through my server side logic:

```
function isCalendlyEvent(e) {
    return e.data.event &&
        e.data.event.indexOf('calendly') === 0;
};

window.addEventListener(
    'message',
    function (e) {
        if (isCalendlyEvent(e)) {
            if (e.data['event'] == 'calendly.event_scheduled') {

                let data = {
                    eventUri: e.data.payload.event.uri,
                    inviteeUri: e.data.payload.invitee.uri
                };

                fetch("https://localhost:5001/CoachSessions/AddSession", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                }).then(res => {

                    //TODO Add Callback from JS Event listener to Blazor Instance Method
                      if (res.status == 200) {
                        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('MyApp.ClientSide', 'AddedSession');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
);
```

My problem and question is how can I pass Object Reference when an event is triggered so I could make an instance method callback to my Blazor component?

In the code above I have tried calling a static method and it works but it requires everything else to be static so its not ideal to say the least.
I have also tried random ideas such as passing object references as an data attribute and hooking the object reference to the window object but to no avail.

To clarify, I need this so I can close some modals after a successful scheduling and to limit the user from scheduling more events of the same type.